# downgrading firefox3 (iceweasel) to 2 in debian lenny

Tags: linux, firefox, debian

How do i downgrade iceweasel 3 to 2 in lenny? I tried to use pinning but i think something went wrong (maybe with version i wrote in /etc/apt/preferences) and now 'there's no package available' when i try to apt-get install iceweasel

```
Package: iceweasel
Pin: version 2.0.0.14-2
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting "no package available" because the version you've specified isn't actually available in the [stable (Lenny)](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/iceweasel) repository, and your `sources.list` file probably doesn't include the [oldstable (Etch)](http://packages.debian.org/etch/iceweasel) repository.

But I wouldn't add the old repository immediately.  Instead, download the Etch binary from the link and try to install it manually:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i iceweasel_2.0.0.19-0etch1_i386.deb
```

If you run into dependency problems, purge that package (`sudo apt-get purge iceweasel`) and make a choice:

- Enable the oldstable repository and install with aptitude, which might downgrade other packages while attempting to satisfy dependencies; or
- Grab the sources (also available from the Etch link, in the right-hand sidebar), install the build prerequisites, and compile your own version of the package.

Whichever route you decide on, your "Hold" should now work.